# Memory leak in CABasicAnimation

Tags: ios, memory-management

The following code points to a memory allocation leak (using the allocation tool in profiler) - 
Can someone point out why - 
I am using a `CABAsicAnimation` to rotate a `UIImageView`

```
-(void)SetGaugeToValueInAngles: (int)newValue
{

    static int oldValue = 0;

    int delta = newValue - oldValue;

    CABasicAnimation *rotate = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
    [rotate setDelegate:self];
    rotate.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:oldValue/57.2958];
    rotate.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    rotate.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;

    rotate.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:  newValue/57.2958];

    rotate.duration = 10.0; // seconds

    [self.UIImageViewPressureMark.layer addAnimation:rotate forKey:nil]; // "key" is optional

    NSLog(@"Old Value %d New Value %d", oldValue, newValue);

    oldValue = newValue;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set `removeOnCompletion` to `NO` the layer will retain the animation until you remove it.

You should either set `removedOnCompletion` to `YES`, or check to see if the layer already has the animation and remove it when you add the next newValue

Comment: @peko is saying that the layer is retaining the animation, causing you to add lots of duplicate animations every time you call this method.  You should either set `removedOnCompletion` to `YES`, or check to see if the layer already has the animation and remove it when you add the next `newValue`.

Comment: @AaronBrager added your comment to my answer.

Comment: I understand the issue -
Changing removedOnCompletion to Yes fixes the issue however just by changing the animation key from a nil(for key:nil) to something else (for key @"foobar") also fixes the issue.  Can anyone explain why providing the key to the animation and keeping the removedOnCompletion to No works.

Answer (score 0):

You should call removeAnimationForKey when you release instance of this class.
Do as following
1.change

```
[self.UIImageViewPressureMark.layer addAnimation:rotate forKey:nil];
```

to

```
[self.UIImageViewPressureMark.layer addAnimation:rotate forKey:@"myAnimation"];
```

in your method "SetGaugeToValueInAngles"

2.call following method when you relase instance of this class

```
- (void)invalateAnimation
{
    [self.UIImageViewPressureMark.layer removeAnimationForKey:@"myAnimation"];
    self.UIImageViewPressureMark.layer = nil;
}
```